# How are Serial Communications designed to be connected virtually on Dell PowerEdge 12th generation servers?

Tags: dell-poweredge, dell, terminal, serial

Im trying to figure out what exactly can be configured by the first three settings on [Dell PowerEdge R720 Server BIOS's Serial Communications Screen](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/de-de/poweredge-r720/720720xdom/serial-communications-screen?guid=guid-4063d043-92ad-478a-911c-14b587261e11&lang=en-us).

Let me explain what (I think) I have understood:

Disregarding all Input operations, there are or may be multiple *sources* (in terms of output) of serial communication:

- Startup process/POST/BIOS itself
- Serial Console 1 of OS
- Serial Console 2 of OS
  (As far as I have read, the OS usually has two (virtual) serial ports for historic reasons.)

On the other hand I have these serial communication *sinks* in mind:

- A terminal emulator connected to the physical serial port on servers rear side
- A NIC from where the signal ist transmited over network
- virtual Console in iDRAC e.g. in Browser interface

---

What I do not understand is this:

1. What is meant by *console redirection* as configured by the first option in the menu named above? Which *console* is meant here?
2. What is the difference between *Serial Port Address* (COM1/COM2 here) and *Serial Device* as named in second setting?
3. If the *External Serial Connector* is the physical serial port on the rear side, what is meant by *remote access device*? Else, what is the *External Serial Connector*?

Comment: I work at Dell but this is way before my time. I came in for 14G and the oldest I've seen in the field is 13G . I'll ask around but if it helps, on 13G+ servers you can connect a USB->Ethernet cable to the front of the chassis and you can hit the iDRAC on the IPv4 169.254.0.0/16 range. That's kind of similar? What it really sounds like is on the VEP series you use a console cable to do everything. It will literally give you UI over the terminal. This looks a lot like that does. I'll ask one of the "older" guys and see if they know

Comment: @GrantCurell I would be glad if you could help me with that. Just to make it clear: I am aware that there exist configuration options using iDARC/IPMI/LOM, Lifecycle Manager and others (physical interaction at least) but want to get a rough Idea what options for serial communication with the server itself and maybe also the OS I have. Therefore I consider understanding what the single options for these settings actualy stand for an requirement. But unfortunately I stumbled with this already...

Answer (score 0):

I *think* the below is correct. I obviously don't have an R720 to go test against. If anything doesn't line up let me know and I'll edit the response.

> What is meant by console redirection as configured by the first option
> in the menu named above? Which console is meant here?

It's referring to redirecting a given console source (BIOS, host, etc) to some target port. See Additional Context

> What is the difference between Serial Port Address (COM1/COM2 here)
> and Serial Device as named in second setting?

The serial device is the receiving target: BIOS, host, etc. See Additional Context

> If the External Serial Connector is the physical serial port on the
> rear side, what is meant by remote access device? Else, what is the
> External Serial Connector?

It's referring to a device that takes serial in and does IP out (typically). Before SOL was a thing, you would have an external device [like this one](https://www.cdw.com/product/lantronix-uds-2100-2-port-serial-device-server/1113429) that would take the serial input and convert it to IP for you.

#### Additional Context

[image]